# JQuery animation is working differently in IE/Opera, Chrome, Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

i have animation of image which is not working correctly in latest chrome and firefox and it's working fine in IE8 and latest Opera

http://jsfiddle.net/wzHx3/7/ and the full screen example http://dev.fama.net.pl/tides/ - click on the right triangle to trigger animation and than click on the left one to trigger second animation

UPDATE - second animation in Chrome is now fixed thx to afshin

UPDATE 2 - all Chrom issues are fixed thx to afshin

ISSUE - Firefox: first animation is shorter than animation in other browsers and second one is preceded by big jump to the right

Chrome, IE8 and Opera works perfect

JQUERY

```
$(window).load(function(){

    var speed = 500;
    var times = 2;
    var loop = setInterval(anim, 500);
    function anim(){
        times--;
        if(times === 0){clearInterval(loop);}
        $('#arrow-right').animate({right:-1,opacity:.2},speed).animate({right:-15, opacity:.5},speed);
    }
    anim(); 

    $('#bg img.pic').css('opacity','0');
});
$(document).ready(function(){

    var easing = 'easeInOutCubic';

$('#arrow-right').click(function(){
    $('#bg img.pic').animate({left:'0%', opacity: 1}, 2500, function() {
        $('#arrow-left').animate({left:0}, 800, easing);
    });
    $(this).animate({right:-125}, 800, easing);

});    

$('#arrow-left').click(function(){
    $('#bg img.pic').animate({left: '20%', opacity: 0}, 2500, easing, function() {
        $('#arrow-right').animate({right:-15}, 800, easing);
        //$(this).css('left','75%');
    });        
    $(this).animate({left:-125}, 800, easing);
});
});
```

CSS

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

body,html {
    overflow: hidden
}
#bg {
    position:fixed; 
    top:-50%; 
    left:-50%; 
    width:200%; 
    height:200%;
}
#bg img {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    margin:auto; 
    min-width:50%;
    min-height:50%;
}
#bg img.blank {
    z-index: 0;
}
#bg img.pic {
    z-index: 1;
    left: 20%;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -120px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity:.5;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 120px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 120px solid transparent;         
}
.arrow:hover {
    opacity:.2 !important;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)" !important;
}
#arrow-left {
    border-left: 120px solid #83bedd;
    left: -125px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#arrow-right {
    border-right: 120px solid #83bedd;
    right: -15px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bg">
    <img class="blank" src="http://dev.fama.net.pl/tides/img/bg.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="pic" src="http://dev.fama.net.pl/tides/img/bga.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
<div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: seemslike everything is fine only difference between them is the speed of animation. may be you should change your opacity faster than the animation.. problem only occurs with webkits. such as safari - chrome and maxthon.

Comment: The "jumps" are most likely caused by using `margin: auto` to center your image. Changing `margin: auto` to `margin-top: auto` and `margin: bottom: auto` stops the jumps for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wzHx3/2/

Comment: @My Head Hurts your way helps in firefox THX :] but not in webkits

Comment: @gidzior that is the `-1` in `$('#bg img.pic').animate`, changing that to `0` removes the webkit issue for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wzHx3/3/

Comment: yeah for me too but setting margin-top: auto and margin: bottom: auto is not working, this cause that img in not scaling any more so it's not solving firefox issue

Comment: @gidzior I didn't mean to imply that was the fix, I was trying to show that was the cause of the problem. The fix would be to remove `margin: auto` and scale your images in a different way

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: AFAIK, there's not such thing as `auto` for `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.  [According to the box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins), if `auto` is used for top/bottom `margin`, it's replaced with `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out maybe help

```
$('#arrow-right').click(function(){
    $('#bg img.pic').animate({left:'0%', opacity: 1}, 2500, function() {
        $('#arrow-left').animate({left:0}, 800, easing);
    });
    $(this).animate({right:-125}, 800, easing);

});    

$('#arrow-left').click(function(){
    $('#bg img.pic').animate({left: 20+'%', opacity: 0}, 2500, easing, function() {
        $('#arrow-right').animate({right:-15}, 800, easing);
        //$(this).css('left','75%');
    });        
    $(this).animate({left:-125}, 800, easing);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzHx3/7/)

Comment: your way eliminated a small jump in the second animation in webkit, thx

Comment: but first animation is still much more shorter than in others browsers

Comment: @gidzior I changed my answer take a look .

Comment: hehehe yes it's fixing webkit's issues but now first animation in firefox is same as was in webkit so it's to short and before secend animation is still a jump

Comment: in firefox it is ok in the very small window for example 600x600 but when window is bigger animation is broken